# Tensorflow keep loaded model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm developing an application and to take advantage of the code, I developed a class for reading tensorflow models:

```
class tf_model(object):

    def __init__(self, modelo_pb, modelo_txt, qtd_classes, inferencia_min, frame):
        self.modelo_pb = modelo_pb
        self.modelo_txt = modelo_txt
        self.qtd_classes = qtd_classes
        self.inferencia_min = inferencia_min
        self.frame = frame

        self.reader_model(self.modelo_pb, self.modelo_txt, self.qtd_classes, self.inferencia_min, self.frame)

    def reader_model(self, modelo_pb, modelo_txt, qtd_classes, inferencia_min, frame):
        PATH_TO_CKPT = self.modelo_pb
        # List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
        PATH_TO_LABELS = self.modelo_txt
        NUM_CLASSES = self.qtd_classes


        detection_graph = tf.Graph()
        with detection_graph.as_default():
            od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
                serialized_graph = fid.read()
                od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
                tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

        label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
        categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES,
                                                                    use_display_name=True)
        category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

        with detection_graph.as_default():
            with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
                while True:
                    image_np = self.frame
                    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
                    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
                    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
                    # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
                    boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
                    # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
                    # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
                    scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')

                    classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
                    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
                    # Actual detection.
                    (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
                        [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
                        feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
                        # Visualization of the results of a detection.

                    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                        image_np,
                        np.squeeze(boxes),
                        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                        np.squeeze(scores),
                        category_index,
                        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                        min_score_thresh=self.inferencia_min,
                        line_thickness=8)
```

for the class I pass the necessary parameters for read a tensorflow model, but i need that the model keep loaded after first call.

example:

I have the call script, the script read my webcam img:

```
while True:
    frame = camera.get_frame()
    if frame is not None:

        tf_model = tf_model('modelos/qar_aciaria.pb','modelos/qar_aciaria.pbtxt',3,0.89,frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        camera.disconnect()
        cv2.destroyWindow('frame')
```

In the first time then I call `tf_model = tf_model('modelos/qar_aciaria.pb','modelos/qar_aciaria.pbtxt',3,0.89,frame)` I need that the model has loaded and the second time I need that the script use the previous loaded model.

Currently, the model is loaded on each frame, making the system very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to split the model load and inference into 2 functions instead of all in the reader_model. And only load the model once at the beginning and call inference/predict for each frame received later.

Besides, think if you need to inference for each frame of the camera and what is the through output of your model, batching the multiple frame into one round could also an option to speed the process.

```
class tf_model(object):

    def __init__(self, modelo_pb, modelo_txt, qtd_classes, inferencia_min):
        self.modelo_pb = modelo_pb
        self.modelo_txt = modelo_txt
        self.qtd_classes = qtd_classes
        self.inferencia_min = inferencia_min

        self.reader_model(self.modelo_pb, self.modelo_txt, self.qtd_classes, self.inferencia_min)

    def reader_model(self, modelo_pb, modelo_txt, qtd_classes, inferencia_min):
        PATH_TO_CKPT = self.modelo_pb
        # List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
        PATH_TO_LABELS = self.modelo_txt
        NUM_CLASSES = self.qtd_classes


        detection_graph = tf.Graph()
        with detection_graph.as_default():
            od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
                serialized_graph = fid.read()
                od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
                tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

        label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
        categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES,
                                                                    use_display_name=True)
        category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)
        self.image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
        self.boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
        # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
        self.scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')

        self.classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        self.num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

    def predict(self, frame):
         image_np = frame
         # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
         image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)

                # Actual detection.
         (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = self.sess.run(
                    [self.boxes, self.scores, self.classes, self.num_detections],
                    feed_dict={self.image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
                    # Visualization of the results of a detection.

          vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                    image_np,
                    np.squeeze(boxes),
                    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                    np.squeeze(scores),
                    category_index,
                    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                    min_score_thresh=self.inferencia_min,
                    line_thickness=8)


###############main###########
model=tf_model('modelos/qar_aciaria.pb','modelos/qar_aciaria.pbtxt',3,0.89)
while True:
    frame = camera.get_frame()
    model.predict(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        camera.disconnect()
        cv2.destroyWindow('frame')
```

Comment: I tried this, but system return name 'detection_graph' is not defined.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. Just updated the code. You can have a try, I have not run it. But the idea should be clear.

Comment: Ok, this work but how do i pass the parameters in tf_model('modelos/qar_aciaria.pb','modelos/qar_aciaria.pbtxt',3,0.89)
Example:
tf_model(self.modelo_pb....)

Comment: @MatheusArruda, I did not get your question. how do you want the parameters passed in?